# Config::set() sets connection to unwanted setting

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm working with a message queue with 40 listening daemon workers. The queue will always have messages in it, so the workers work continuously. There are messages for different customers in the queue and I have to set the database according to the xml data contained in the queue's payload.

When using `Config::set()` to set the database during runtime, the data gets inserted into various databases, in the correct tables - but in the wrong database. There are many equal databases.

I'm trying to set the database with

`Config::set('database.connections.usertable.database',$database);`

directly before the connection is made. I also tried `Config::set()` directly before each (and also only some or one) `$table->create()` statements, without success.

According to Laravel's documentation, `Config::set()` should be valid for this request only, but it seems like it is confusing the settings when there are multiple connections that set configuration values at the exact same time.

Though I have now solved above issue by extending `Model` by `setConnection()` and `getConnection()` and a different configuration, I'm curious why this happens.

Shouldn't the Config only be set for the exact request it is set in?

Comment: i think what u ve done is a proper way. But read this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-change-default-database-connection-dynamically?page=1#reply-45910 and look this https://github.com/uxweb/laravel-multi-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graham Campbell just answered the question on github:

> Everything is persisted when you have daemon workers. They are NOT
>   requests.